# Does a PHP function finish running before the code below is executed?

Tags: php, mysql

If I have the code below, will the function always completely finish before the code below it is executed?  So let's say the function below saves some stuff to a "clients" table, then I get the client directly below it in the code, is it possible the function may not have finished before I get the client data?

```
// save first shipment data
save_clients_first_shipments($account_id, $client_id);

// get the updated client data
$client = $this->model_clients->getClient( $account_id, $client_id );
```

Thanks!

Comment: It depends on how the first function works. In general it is possible for the first function to trigger an asynchronous process which may or may not be finished by the time the second function is executed. Most likely this is not the case though. If it's just using built-in PHP database methods the second statement won't be executed until the first finishes.

Comment: Almost everything in PHP is synchronous.

Comment: That's what I thought, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Technically anything could be happening inside `save_clients_first_shipments()`, but it would be very unusual for anything to be going on other than that function being called, completing, and the process flow continuing onward.